# Enlarge a svg image in org

Tags: org-mode, images

I have such a svg picture

```
and test equality by using the following relations:
[[file:fig/math/55d25a70d9db3c6d95666151a04c4869.svg]]
We can express these rules as procedures:
```

[image]

Then enlarge it

[image]

What's the problem and the decent solution to enlarge a svg image?

Comment: With Emacs 26.3 and Org 9.1.9 I can reproduce the blurred appearance of the enlarged image but not the disappearance of the letters. I can only imagine that the disappearance of the letters is connected with a defective version of `libimagemagick`.